# Event Delegation - Element Style Issues - Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, delegation

Having an issue whereby I can click on each individual element and the target element comes back as being clicked but when applying a style, it only applies to first element rather than any other targetted element.

Event Delegation works as said above I can click on each element on it'll come back as being clicked, just style doesn't apply

Below is a seperate written example to try and debug this issue but I'm stumped

```js
giphyContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);

    if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Front1")) {
        console.log("clicked! 1")
        frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
        backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Front2")) {
        console.log("clicked! 2")
        frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
        backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Front3")) {
        console.log("clicked! 3")
        frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
        backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Back1")) {
        frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
        backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Back2")) {
        frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
        backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
    }

    if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Back3")) {
        frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
        backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="giphyContainer">
    <div class="giphyImg">
        <img src="img1.png" alt="" class="giphyImg__Front giphyImg__Front1">
        <div class="giphyImg__Back giphyImg__Back1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="giphyImg">
        <img src="img2.png" alt="" class="giphyImg__Front giphyImg__Front2">
        <div class="giphyImg__Back giphyImg__Back2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="giphyImg">
        <img src="img3.png" alt="" class="giphyImg__Front giphyImg__Front3">
        <div class="giphyImg__Back giphyImg__Back3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're setting the style of the same `frontPanel` and `backPanel` elements every time. That's just one element for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the global values of `frontPanel` and `backPanel`, which don't change depending on which image you click on.

You need to set `frontPanel` and `backPanel` to the front and back images in the same DIV as the clicked element.

```js
giphyContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
  let frontPanel = e.target.closest("div.giphyImg").querySelector(".giphyImg__Front");
  let backPanel = e.target.closest("div").querySelector(".giphyImg__Back");
  
  if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Front1")) {
    console.log("clicked! 1")
    frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
    backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Front2")) {
    console.log("clicked! 2")
    frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
    backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Front3")) {
    console.log("clicked! 3")
    frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
    backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Back1")) {
    frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
    backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Back2")) {
    frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
    backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
  }

  if (e.target.classList.contains("giphyImg__Back3")) {
    frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
    backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
  }
})
```

Comment: Since same computation is repeated. Furthermore code can optimize to :                                                               
`const classList = e.target.classList;
if (classList.contains("giphyImg__Front1") || classList.contains("giphyImg__Front2") || classList.contains("giphyImg__Front3")) {
 frontPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
 backPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
}else{
 frontPanel.style.zIndex = 3;
 backPanel.style.zIndex = -3;
}`

Comment: Yes, there's lots of DRY possible here. I assumed there's actually more to it in the actual application, and each if block really needs to do something different.

Comment: Right. I just suggested looking at the current code sample. WIll surely change if any checks need to be done other than just for Front and Back classes

Comment: For that matter, there doesn't seem to be a need to have separate checks for `Front1`, `Front2`, etc. It can just be delegated to `giphyImg__Front` and `giphyImg__Back`

Comment: But I'm treating the log messages as a placeholder for the different actions in each block.

Comment: Lots of code optimization can happen. We can get element index to be used in console.log `const index = Array.from(e.target.parentElement.children).indexOf(e.target)`

Answer (score 0):

simply do

```html
<div class="giphyContainer">
  <div class="giphyImg">
    <img src="img1.png" alt="" class="giphyImg__Front">
    <div class="giphyImg__Back></div>
  </div>
  <div class="giphyImg">
    <img src="img2.png" alt="" class="giphyImg__Front">
    <div class="giphyImg__Back"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="giphyImg">
    <img src="img3.png" alt="" class="giphyImg__Front">
    <div class="giphyImg__Back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
const giphyContainer = document.querySelector('.giphyContainer')


giphyContainer.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('.giphyImg__Back,.giphyImg__Front')) return
    
  let 
    parent  = target.closest('div.giphyImg')
  , isFront = target.matches('.giphyImg__Front')
    ;
  parent.querySelector('.giphyImg__Front').style.zIndex = isFront ? -3 : 3
  parent.querySelector('.giphyImg__Back').style.zIndex  = isFront ? 3 : -3
  }
```

> but there is much simpler to do:

```js
const giphyContainer = document.querySelector('.giphyContainer')

giphyContainer.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('.giphyImg, .giphyImg > img')) return
    
  target.closest('div.giphyImg').classList.toggle('front')
  }
```

```css
div.giphyImg { 
  display    : inline-block;
  margin     : 10px 5px;
  cursor     : pointer;
  background : teal;
  font-size  : 0;
  }
div.giphyImg > img       { visibility: hidden;  } 
div.giphyImg.front > img { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<div class="giphyContainer">
  <div class="giphyImg ">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/160/200" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="giphyImg front">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1019/160/200" alt="" >
  </div>
  <div class="giphyImg front">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/160/200" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>
```